# Conditionals with Combining Fields in Views

Tags: views, entities, log-messages

I'm having issues with rewriting the results of a field. I am trying to rewrite the field to be a combinations of 3 fields:

- [field_products]
- [field_downloadable_products]
- [field_product]

When I preview my field I see this:

[image]

Is there a way to add a conditional statement to fix the issue where the other tokens are showing when there isn't a value there for those tokens?

Here is a view of my rewritten results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instated of

```
 [field_products} [field_downloadable_products] [field_product]
```

Try

```
[field_products] [field_downloadable_products] [field_product]
```

Comment: Nope, still get the same issue.

Comment: can you add the screen shot of view settings page on screen.

Comment: you need to check that you put the rewriting the results field at end.

Comment: Do you mean the entire view area? or just the rewrite area?

Comment: view area fields list and rewrite area.

Comment: rewrite area screenshot is in the original post and I just posted the View fields area. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you do not write in ""rewrite area"" you able to see the field content on output right? Also please delete the post form Answer.

Comment: Now It's working! I moved the fields around and realized I was using the incorrect field and order.

Comment: Nice to hear ... :)